# Junit Testing : org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit4

I am trying to write `JUnit` test case for post request. I am trying to send body for post request. I tried like below But I am getting  `org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException`  can any one please tell me what I am missing in below code?

**JSON format**

```
{        
    "nAccountId":651754,
     "sLocation": "B",
     "nAccountCPCMappingid":8,
     "sAcctDesc":" FY07 GEN GIFTS" ,
     "nDeptId":21728,
     "sClientAcctId":"2100012",
     "nInvestigatorId":65760

}
```

I tried like this

```
String json = "{\n" + 
                "        \"nAccountId\":\"651754\", \"sLocation\": \"B\",\n" + 
                "         \"nAccountCPCMappingid\":\"8\",\"sAcctDesc\":\" FY07 GEN GIFTS\" ,\n" + 
                "         \"nDeptId\":\"21728\", \"sClientAcctId\":\"2100012\",\n" + 
                "         \"nInvestigatorId\":\"65760\" }";
```

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "{
        "nAccountId":"651754", "sLocation": "B",
         "nAccountCPCMappingid":"8","sAcctDesc":" FY07 GEN GIFTS" ,
         "nDeptId":"21728", "sClientAcctId":"2100012",
         "nInvestigatorId":"65760" }": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:452)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.contentType(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:272)
    at com.spacestudy.AccountControllerTest.btnSaveClickTest(AccountControllerTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "{
        "nAccountId":"651754", "sLocation": "B",
         "nAccountCPCMappingid":"8","sAcctDesc":" FY07 GEN GIFTS" ,
         "nDeptId":"21728", "sClientAcctId":"2100012",
         "nInvestigatorId":"65760" }": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:256)
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:449)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 3):

After seeing your error log it is pretty much clear that **Content-Type** is wrong which should be **application/json**  but you passes the JSON object itself as Content-Type. See below line carefully

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "{
        "nAccountId":"651754", "sLocation": "B",
         "nAccountCPCMappingid":"8","sAcctDesc":" FY07 GEN GIFTS" ,
         "nDeptId":"21728", "sClientAcctId":"2100012",
         "nInvestigatorId":"65760" }": does not contain '/'
```

Check again the configurations and code you will definitely find out yourself.

Comment: I solved my error. There is no problem in `String json`.  problem was  I am writing `contentType(json)` instead of `content`

Answer (score 2):

The interesting part of your stracktrace is there :

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "{
        "nAccountId":"651754", "sLocation": "B",
         "nAccountCPCMappingid":"8","sAcctDesc":" FY07 GEN GIFTS" ,
         "nDeptId":"21728", "sClientAcctId":"2100012",
         "nInvestigatorId":"65760" }": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:452)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.contentType(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:272)
    at com.spacestudy.AccountControllerTest.btnSaveClickTest(AccountControllerTest.java:51)
```

We can read that the `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.contentType(String contentType)` method sets the `Content-Type` header of the request to build but it received as parameter for an invalid one : the JSON object itself.
It says exactly that `does not contain '/'` because a `Content-Type` should have a `/` character in its value such as [these one](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types).
So you should check your actual code to create the request as you seem to pass the JSON object as header in the `Content-Type` header while you should pass a `String` value such as `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks for your giving time and suggestion. problem is I am writing `ContentType` instead of `content` and passing string JSON variable in that

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this part of of your code

```
String json = "{\n" + 
                "        \"nAccountId\":\"651754\", \"sLocation\": \"B\",\n" + 
                "         \"nAccountCPCMappingid\":\"8\",\"sAcctDesc\":\" FY07 GEN GIFTS\" ,\n" + 
                "         \"nDeptId\":\"21728\", \"sClientAcctId\":\"2100012\",\n" + 
                "         \"nInvestigatorId\":\"65760\" }";
```

Comment: I solved my error. There is no problem in `String json`.  problem was  I am writing `contentType(json)` instead of `content`